# DRF Django filter range for a CharField

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I needed to save creation time as string in model, so I used CharField.
But now I have problem filtering by queryparams for obtain objects in range of two times. I see that 'lte' and 'gte' are not working for strings.

Anyone have some ideas on how i could do that?

Comment: Why did you save it as a string? That sounds like the wrong thing to do to start with.

Comment: I think it is rather strange to store a timestamp as a `CharField`. It looks like "bad design" since by using a `CharField`, you allow users to enter all kinds of data, in all kinds of formats in the database. I really advise to redesign this, and use a `DateField` or `DateTimeField`.

Comment: I'm using it only inside app, noone can post, patch or update. I wanted to save issues with formatting datetime into DateTimeField but that was probably bad designed, have to refactor that.

Comment: @slqq: the fact that noone can post/patch/update/... is not really relevant. The nice thing about a `DateTimeField` is that it provides a *contract* that all data are valid `DateTimeField`s. It might require some parsing (although Django has some support for this), but then you kknow at least that the data is *valid*.

Comment: Yeah, i agree, and it allow to have cohesion all over dates in app, since DateTimeFields are using format from settings. Thanks for advice. :)